# Flag duplicates/triplicates or higher based on 2 variables in SAS

Tags: duplicates, sas

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1989 |
| A | 1989 |
| A | 1989 |
| B | 1990 |
| B | 1990 |
| C | 1991 |
| C | 1992 |

And want to output data with an additional Flag variable such that the first record of a duplicate or higher is 0, the second is 1, etc. based on both ID and Year. Observations that have a unique combination of ID and Year would not be flagged:

| ID | Year | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1989 | 0 |
| A | 1989 | 1 |
| A | 1989 | 2 |
| B | 1990 | 0 |
| B | 1990 | 1 |
| C | 1991 |  |
| C | 1992 |  |

I am only familiar with proc sort nodupkey as a way to eliminate duplicates, but I want to instead retain all data and add a flagging variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID $ Year;
datalines;
A 1989
A 1989
A 1989
B 1990
B 1990
C 1991
C 1992
;

data want;
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.Year);
      set have;
      by ID Year;
   end;

   do flag = 0 to _N_ - 1;
      set have;
      if _N_ = 1 then flag = .;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

**Result:**

```
ID  Year  flag
A   1989  0
A   1989  1
A   1989  2
B   1990  0
B   1990  1
C   1991  .
C   1992  .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count.  Use BY group processing and a SUM statement.

Personally, when I count things I start the numbering from ONE.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id year;
  flag+1;
  if first.year then flag=1;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    id    year    flag

 1     A     1989      1
 2     A     1989      2
 3     A     1989      3
 4     B     1990      1
 5     B     1990      2
 6     C     1991      1
 7     C     1992      1
```

If you want the singletons to be different then test for observations that are both the first and the last of the group.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id year;
  flag+1;
  if first.year then flag=1;
  if first.year and last.year then flag=0;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    id    year    flag

 1     A     1989      1
 2     A     1989      2
 3     A     1989      3
 4     B     1990      1
 5     B     1990      2
 6     C     1991      0
 7     C     1992      0
```

Note Since SAS will treat zero or missing as FALSE and any other value as TRUE you can use FLAG as a boolean.

```
proc print data=want;
  title 'Distinct records';
  where not flag;
run;
```

Comment: Your result is not what I'm looking for. Obs 1 is the first in a triplicate set, and I want to have it uniquely flagged as such. Obs 6 and obs 7 should not have a flag because they do not have a duplicate by ID and Year. At least, they should not also have the same flag as obs 1.

Comment: As stated test for both first and last to find the singletons.

Comment: It seems like this solution is only taking into account the Year variable... for example, if we had an obs 8 that had ID=4 and Year=1992. Obs 7 and obs 8 should NOT be a duplicate because they do not have identical ID and Year.

Comment: The BY variables are nested.   So since ID='4' is different than ID='C' observation 8 would be the first observation for YEAR=1992 within the set of observations where ID='4'.